# How to change the name of a button in a for loop in Java Android

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if you can help me. I want to simplify this code in java for android. Is there a way to do it?

```
    btn1.setText(rnd[0]);
    btn2.setText(rnd[1]);
    btn3.setText(rnd[2]);
    btn4.setText(rnd[3]);
    btn5.setText(rnd[4]);
```

I was thinking in a for loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<5; i++) {
    btn1.setText(rnd[i]);
}
```

But how can I change the number of btn? Is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: You can have an array of buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final List<Button> myButtons = Arrays.asList(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5)
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   myButtons.get(i).setText(rnd[i])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Button[] btn_arr=new Button[rnd.length];
for(int i = 0; i < rnd.length; i++) {
btn_arr[i].setText(rnd[i]); 
}
```

Comment: this is fine but you need an extra loop to first populate the array